# how to throw InvalidArgumentException built-in exceptions in Symfony v2.8/PHP v5.6

Tags: php, exception, throw, symfony-2.8, invalid-argument

This question was answered, but it brought up a question about how to catch the InvalidArgumentException, which I added in the ***Update*** section.

***  Original Question ***

I am using Symfony v2.8 and PHP v5.6, and I want to throw an InvalidArgumentException exception in the function, containing the below code, when the $id parameter does not have an integer value:

```
function vote( $id ) {

  if( !is_integer( $id ) ) 

      throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'An invalid argument was specified ...' );

  else ...

      // Add a vote to the record specified by the $id parameter ...

  ⫶

}
```

In my code, the actual message will be more meaningful

Unlike the PHP Manual's example showing this [throw-exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php), Symfony outputs the following error when I load a page that causes the above code to execute on my server:

```
Attempted to load class "InvalidArgumentException" from namespace 
"AppBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. 
"Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Asset\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException", 
"Doctrine\Instantiator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException" or 
"Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\InvalidArgumentException"?
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException
```

I could add all of these components to my class's USE list, and that might work, but that seems like overkill because most, if not all, don't seem to apply to the context where I'm checking the $id parameter, but after looking at each one of the suggested components I don't see any that appear to apply to creating a general function argument trap for a function's $id parameter that isn't an integer type.  I've looked through the Symfony site's documentation for using this exception and tried to find a component that 'fits' my intended usage, but couldn't find anything that applied.

Please, would someone who has used this exception in their Symfony code, tell me which of the component(s) in the suggested component list or some other component that I should add to my code so it can properly throw the InvalidArgumentException exception?

*** Update ***

I'm currently catching a database attempt to insert a duplicate row error as follows:

```
catch( \Exception $e ) {

    if( get_class( $e ) ===
        'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException' ) {

        if( $command === 'vote' )

            return 'You may only vote once on an Artist\'s ' .
                   ( ( $media === 'Songs' ) ? 'song' : 'video' ) . '.';

        else

                return '';

        // End of if( $command === 'vote' ) ...

    }
    else

        throw $e; // Re-Throw all other exceptions.

    // End of if( get_class( $e ) !==
    //            'Doctrine\...\UniqueConstraintViolationException' ) ...
    //        else ...

} // End of try ... catch( \Exception $e ) ...
```

In the case of the Unique Constraint Violation Exception, I look for it with the 'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException' class name string, but in the USE statement, I have use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException, but the two are different.

*** Update ***

I currently don't want to handle the InvalidArgumentException, but if I did, is there a class name for it?  This exception doesn't have a corresponding USE statement, so I haven't found one when I searched for one.

More broadly, how do you determine what class names are used for each exception you want to catch?  Is there such a list for Symfony exception handling?

Thanks

Comment: Use \InvalidArgumentException() with the start slash

Comment: Thank you very much!  I continued to search for Symfony Use InvalideArgumentException since submitting this question, but that didn't lead to a solution.  I retyped 'thow new ' in my code, and my editor, which  supports smart code completion, offered a list of exceptions that it 'knew' about.  This was a feature I didn't know about!  I've been looking for a list of exception that I could use in various throw new situations, but never found one.  Anyway I chose the one you suggested and it worked without needing to add a component to my USE list.  GREAT - Thanks again.

Comment: I complete my answer (yesturday, i was on phone, and StackOverflow is not easy on phone :p). This is a namespace problem.
At the very begining of your file you have a `namespace AppBundle\Controller`, so it means that all the future classes your will use have to be search in src/AppBundle/Controller directory. So when you call `InvalidArgumentException` it try to search it in this dir and fail, that's what the error says. When use a prefix `\` it means that it will search at the "root" of the code, i.e. PHP native

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, so putting a slash before InvalidArgumentException() tell the compiler that InvalidArgumentException isn't in the AppBundle\Controler, but in the 'root', correct?

Comment: I've updated my question with a question about catching this exception.  If you don't mind, please take a look at the update.  Thanks.

Comment: You've understood ;)